# I need \r\n instead of \n in text

Tags: python, format, character

When I open a file in Python and read it in I get this format:  `Data\r\n\r\n\t`

When I paste it I get text without formatting characters, which I encode like this:

```
encoded = clipboard.encode('utf8')
```

The result looks like this: `Data\n\n\t`

I need the first result with the `\r\n` instead of just `\n`

Is there a different .encode to use?
Or another simple way to end up with the `\r\n` characters?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to specify what language this is...? (By adding it as a tag.)

Comment: What is in `clipboard`, and where did it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 encoded = clipboard.encode('utf8').replace("\n","\r\n")
```

I suspect clipboard is removing the "\r\n" and changing it to the more standard "\n" ... this will simply replace all "\n" with "\r\n"

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked. but it threw an error unless I did the .replace before the .encode.

Answer (score 1):

The linux command [unix2dos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) can help you out here, probably.
Reverse command is dos2unix.

Both commands are used to change formats between LF-ended and CRLF-ended line files.

Comment: I believe he is inside of python ... so its probably easier to just do a replace ... but I guess this works(+1)